# Force URL pattern to specific balancer member in apache

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I have a load balancer in apache with currently only two members. I want the URL's starting with "admin" to be mapped to a specific instance (http://localhost:16666/) because the admin site needs access to files on the CDN which is also in this machine. I could handle this by mounting this folder to the other server, or implementing a separate service doing this, but that's the last thing I want now. I was about to create a new proxypass rule to map these to this member rather than the balancer, but it simply ignores it.

The important part of my vhost config:

```
            <Location /balancer-manager>
               SetHandler balancer-manager
            </Location>

            <Proxy balancer://videoportal>
                    BalancerMember http://localhost:16666
                    BalancerMember http://example.com:16666
                    Require all granted
                    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
            </Proxy>

            <Proxy *>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/videoportal-error.log

            ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
            ProxyPass "/admin"  "http://localhost:16666/admin"
            ProxyPassReverse "/admin" "http://localhost:16666/admin"

            ProxyPass / balancer://videoportal/
            ProxyPassReverse / balancer://videoportal/
            ProxyRequests Off
```

Any advice what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you are mixing apache 2.2 and apache 2.4 config

In apache 2.2 use

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

***//Your apache config//***

```
<Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

In apache 2.4

```
Require all granted
```

***//Your apache config//***

```
<Proxy balancer://videoportal>
    ...
    Require all granted
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
 </Proxy>
```

Second try put the /admin before the balancer definition

```
    ...
    SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass "/admin"  "http://localhost:16666/admin"
ProxyPassReverse "/admin" "http://localhost:16666/admin"

<Proxy balancer://videoportal>
      BalancerMember http://localhost:16666
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right about the mixing rules of the order/require.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem.

I created a location rule  for this and added a header to track if it's working:

```
        <Location /balancer-manager>
           SetHandler balancer-manager
        </Location>

        <Proxy balancer://videoportal>
                BalancerMember http://localhost:16666
                BalancerMember http://example.com:16666
                Require all granted
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>

        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/videoportal-error.log

        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !

        # This is the new part
        <Location "/admin">
             ProxyPass "http://localhost:16666/admin"
             ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:16666/admin"
             Header set ADMIN "true"
        </Location>

        # end of new part

        ProxyPass / balancer://videoportal/
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://videoportal/
        ProxyRequests Off
```